# Can not import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I try to **import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity** but my program can not recognize it. I also have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`
and set the apiKey in my project.

Can anybody explain why I can import the above line?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this how to create emulator and all of characteristics for map  http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/

Answer (score 11):

What Android Version to you use ? On your project Settings make sure that you use a Project Build Target that contains the google api. Normally they are names "Google APIs".

I included an image of the project settings. 
[image: Select the one which says "Google APIs". They should include the needed packages.]

Comment: Try it with a different version and clean the project.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem is that I have not imported the maps.jar file in this project...:D

Comment: @detno29, i think if you choose the Build Target as Google API then you don't need to import jar files. You might have some other problem? Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 7):

Right click in your project and select Properties, then select Android > Google APIs from Google Inc. version 2.2 or above. Be sure to choose any of the Google APIs instead of the Android 2.2 or above APIs since only Google APIs have the android.maps library.