# apikey release android

Tags: android, api-key

I don't see the map of google, i make this:

1.Obtain Private Key:

Use Export of Eclipse to sign release application and create new test.keystore with apikey of debug

2.Obtain MD5 certificate:

using alias and keystore set up

use keytool in Java directory: keytool -list -alias testalias -keystore test.keystore

copy MD5 certificate

3.Obtain API Map Key:

Visit http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html and enter MD5 certificate
copy key

4.Use New Map API Key:

insert new map key for string in maps.xml for string mapApiKey

5.Export apk with eclipse android signed with test.keystore

6.Install on device samsung galaxy s but i don't see the map

where is the mistake?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your steps are right, but you need 1 more step.. the key you got is debug key, you need to get release key after you creating the test.keystore.

use this to get it but change the parameters to yours:

```
c:\java\...\bin Keytool –list -alias youraliasname –keystore D:\app\myapp\my_release.keystore -storepass yourpassword -keypass youraliaspassword then enter
```

Comment: sorry, I do not understand when I create a new md5?

Comment: There are two things, debug key, and release key, when you are just debugging you use debug key, when you are ready to publish your application you use release key. If your application don't have maps it will work normal, if you have map ("After creating the release key") you have to do the command in my answer and create new key (release key for map) then you put in your layout which asks for key

Comment: Does it mean that I have to use separate Map API Key, one for debugging, one for release to Google Play ?

Comment: @RajuGujarati It depends on you (You don't have to), but if you want to publish an app, you cannot use the default debugging key, you will have to create release key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify certain things..

1. Did you give INTERNET permission to your app? (In AndroidManifest.xml)
2. Did you mention Google map library in AndroidManifest.xml?
3. maps library must written into application tags and INTERNET permission outside of  application tag.
4. Each MD5 fingerprint can en-cash only 1 API key, and if that API key once used from one device, other cannot use it. It gives no error but maps is not going to display.
5. Did you use MapActivity for displaying map?
6. Your project must built in Google APIs, not in Android. see this ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646292/1160207

Here is example of AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.popup" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Hope this will help. You should post your code for more clear and appropiriate answer.
Thanks...

Comment: yes I used these settings. This is my first code of map and have used the sample code of google, with emulator i see the map with debug.keystore, but when i want try on device i can't see the map. Thanks for reply.